# Using a parameter's property in an ArgumentException

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Our SonarQube often raises the following issue (Code Smell) on our code: "Parameter names used into ArgumentException should match an existing one". [Here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-3928) is the rule that triggers this issue.

An example of this issue being triggered can be the following:

```
private void Validate(SaveCommand command)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(command.UserCode))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command.UserCode));
    ....
}
```

My question is: How do i properly refactor the code to abide by SonarQube (and [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/using-standard-exception-types)) guidelines?

Or should i just keep it like this. If so, why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think SonarQube is spot on here: there's no parameter named `UserCode`, so you shouldn't be specifying it as an argument to the `ArgumentNullException` constructor. I would avoid using `ArgumentNullException` at all here, as the *argument* isn't null - otherwise it would be throwing a `NullReferenceException` at `command.UserCode`.

Instead, just use `ArgumentException` with a descriptive message, e.g.

```
throw new ArgumentException(
    $"{nameof(command.UserCode)} property cannot be null or empty",
    nameof(command));
```

Now we can tell which parameter is incorrect (`command`) and how (its `UserCode` proeprty is null or empty). SonarQube should be fine with this, and it meets the meaning of the exception type more accurately IMO.

Comment: Great catch! (Y)

Comment: Thanks! this makes very much sense :)